# Session issues in Homestead 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, session, homestead

I am using [Laravel Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead) for my php development and working on a project that uses Sessions extensively.

I've noticed that sessions do not persist at all. How can I fix this?

Example:

here's Index.php

```
    <?php

session_start();
$_SESSION['variable'] = 'This Variable';
?>
<html>
<body>
<h1>
<?php
echo $_SESSION['variable'];

?>
</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's sessionCheck.php

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>
    <?php
    session_start();
    print_r($_SESSION);

    ?>
</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Echoes empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Php sessions path did not have the right permissions, hence the the issue.

For homestead, ssh and set the correct permissions as:

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/lib/php/sessions
```

To check your sessions path, use [phpinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php);

Answer (score -2):

Always put session_start at top of line. See the below example

```
<?php
session_start();
        $_SESSION['variable'] = 'This Variable';
        ?>
        <html>
        <body>
        <h1>
        <?php
        echo $_SESSION['variable'];

        ?>
        </h1>

        </body>
    </html>
```

2nd part

```
<?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);

?>
```